# ClassCastException thrown

Tags: java, eclipse, swingutilities

I am trying to create `JFrame` using `SwingUtilities`

```
Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        new Loadingframe();

                    }
                });
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    tt.start();
```

class Loadingframe is a very simple `JFrame`. Sometimes while running this code I get ClassCastException in

```
new Loadingframe();
```

I also tried `InvokeLater` and `Threads only without Swing` but same error too

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException
at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(LayoutComparator.java:75)
at javax.swing.LayoutComparator.compare(LayoutComparator.java:42)
at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:292)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:217)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512)
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1454)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:136)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:110)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:445)
at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getFirstComponent(LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.java:166)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getDefaultComponent(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:535)
at java.awt.FocusTraversalPolicy.getInitialComponent(FocusTraversalPolicy.java:169)
at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.java:420)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4752)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:751)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch(SequencedEvent.java:128)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:749)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:702)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:696)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:724)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:722)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

and for my loading class

```
public class Loadingframe extends JFrame
{
    public Loadingframe()
    {
        this.setType(Type.UTILITY);
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        JButton b = new JButton(
                new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/reso/loading11.png")));
        b.setBorderPainted(false);
        b.setFocusPainted(false);
        b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        add(b);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowFocusListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void windowLostFocus(WindowEvent e)
            {
                Loadingframe.this.dispose();
            }

            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e)
            {
            }
        });
        this.setFocusable(true);
        getContentPane().requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is loading,a class or a method?

Comment: @MehrajMalik a class extends JFrame

Comment: share the stack trace of ClassCastException

Comment: please provide also the code behind new loading()

Comment: @Kareem I thought it was a method,because you have not followed the Naming Convention,if it were a class.

Comment: check the edit ..i am sure code behind loading makes no difference as its simple `jframe`

Comment: oh sorry for that i always forget the capital letter

Comment: cannot reproduce, post code that can reproduce this error please.

Comment: the `new loading()` surronded with swing surronded with thread produce it..but It happens like once per 100 or 200 but its not good as it stops the whole program

Comment: I would recommend that you change the name of your loading class in line with Java coding standards and make it more meaningful e.g. LoadingFrame, LoadingScreen, something like that.

Comment: ok thank you for the hint check the update

Comment: According to the comment in the source of LayoutComparator, this happens if Swing is trying to sort `Component`s one of which is not in the `Window`’s hierarchy. How this could happen with your `JFrame` I have not figured out.

Comment: @KareemElsayed, did you put breakpoint and check what class is expected there?

Comment: so my `SwingUtilites` surronded with `thread` is not the problem ??

Comment: @KareemElsayed what's the purpose of calling SwingUtilities inside another user's thread ? I think this is poor design

Comment: `loadingframe` is just a .gif picture to show the user that something in process so i tried to use normal threads to create `loadingframe` but i found out that swing utilites is responsable for creating Swing things as swing isnt thread safe beside swing cannot be launched but main method 
and my program launches thread that activate the program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you haven't set the platform look and feel or have you ?

Like this

```
try { UIManager.setLookAndFeel("com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsLookAndFeel");
    } catch (Exception e) { }
```

Intermittent errors are sometimes caused because of the Swing components not being registered on the `Componet Hierarchy` that Swing maintains. Typically this happens when we are loading GUI stuff on some other thread than the EDT(`Event Dispatcher Thread`).
To make sure you register the components please do the following,

```
 Thread tt = new Thread(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() {
                            new Loadingframe();

                        }});

                    }
                });
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you please explain why we should use an outer thread `tt`? Isn't it enough to call `EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->{new Loadingframe().setVisible(true);});`?